# Arrange a column using VBA for time format

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to implement a VBA code to arrange the following column A to look like below.

```
Year    Month    Day   Time 
1998      2       1     0
1998      2       1     3
1998      2       1     6
1998      2       1     9
```

and so on.

A =

```
2/1/1998 0:00
2/1/1998 3:00
2/1/1998 6:00
2/1/1998 9:00
2/1/1998 12:00
2/1/1998 15:00
2/1/1998 18:00
2/1/1998 21:00
2/2/1998 0:00
2/2/1998 3:00
2/2/1998 6:00
2/2/1998 9:00
2/2/1998 12:00
2/2/1998 15:00
2/2/1998 18:00
2/2/1998 21:00
```

Comment: Which data is your input and which data is your output?  And have you considered just using the built in date manipulation formulas rather than vba?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Year, Month, Day and Hour formulas in Excel, you don't need VBA.

In B2:

```
=Year(A2)
```

In C2:

```
=Month(A2)
```

In D2:

```
=Day(A2)
```

In E2:

```
=Hour(A2)
```

Drag down